# Is setting substruct values to values returned by pure virtual functions safe in an object constructor?

Tags: c++, virtual-functions

Consider (note some code removed from `object`, i.e. constructors/destructors and some variables):

```
struct object {
    virtual bool object_is_solid() = 0;
    virtual bool object_is_visible() = 0;
    virtual bool object_is_persistent() = 0;
    virtual real_t object_depth() = 0;
    virtual real_t object_sprite_index() = 0;
    virtual real_t object_mask_index() = 0;

    struct object_properties {
      bool solid;
      bool visible;
      bool persistent;
      real_t depth;
      real_t sprite_index;
      real_t mask_index;
      real_t image_alpha;
      real_t image_angle;
      real_t image_blend;
      real_t image_index;
      real_t image_speed;
      real_t image_xscale;
      real_t image_yscale;
      real_t hfriction;
      real_t vfriction;
      real_t hgravity;
      real_t vgravity;
      real_t hspeed;
      real_t vspeed;
    } properties;

    void initialize_properties(object::object_properties& prop);
}
```

and

```
  object::object(unsigned long id, real_t x, real_t y)
    : id(id), xstart(x), ystart(y), x(x), y(y), xprevious(x), yprevious(y), properties{} {
    this->initialize_properties(this->properties);
  }

  void object::initialize_properties(object::object_properties& prop) {
    prop.solid = this->object_is_solid();
    prop.visible = this->object_is_visible();
    prop.persistent = this->object_is_persistent();
    prop.depth = this->object_depth();
    prop.sprite_index = this->object_sprite_index();
    prop.mask_index = this->object_mask_index();
    prop.image_alpha = 1;
    prop.image_speed = 1;
    prop.image_xscale = 1;
    prop.image_yscale = 1;
  }
```

Notice the usage of `initialize_properties`.

1. Is this even safe? If I inline `initialize_properties` manually, clang refuses to compile it because it's calling pure virtual functions in the constructor.
2. Is there a better way for me to initialise `properties` than what I am doing right now?

Comment: It's fine. But why `initialize_properties` should be `inline`? It's a usual implementation detail - keep it in translation unit. Anyway, the architecture is a bit awkward, and requires redesign. Without knowing what you are trying to achieve, examples, and reasoning why you need these additional `bool` members - it's hard to give an answer.

Comment: Actually, from what I read in [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8630160/call-to-pure-virtual-function-from-base-class-constructor) thread, it's unsafe. I guess I'm looking for alternatives then...

Comment: Haroogan: They are mutable and only set at construction to the "default" values for that kind of object.

Comment: Oh, you're calling them in constructor as well - yes, you better not do this. Another reason to redesign.

Comment: No, calling pure virtual functions in a constructor is always a bug (it will crash) and calling non-pure virtual functions in a constructor is nearly always a bug (it won't do what most novices expect it to do).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer: don't do it.

Explanation:
When `object` is constructed, the object is of type `object`, not the derived class yet. Let's call the derived class `my_object`.

Any virtual function (pure or not) that your in object's constructor will call object's version.
Only in the body of `my_object::my_object()` the object type is `my_object`, not before.

The solution is to separate construction from initialization.
From `my_object::my_object()` call a virtual function Initialize or better, expose it as a public method so the code that created the my_object instance will call it to initialize the object.

Example:

```
my_object o;
o.Init(params);
```

Comment: “The solution is to separate construction from initialization”: _A possible_ solution is ... (for example n.m. suggested another one (namely, CRTP) in a comment below)

Comment: Calling static functions is very limiting and is CRTP more complex (code is less readable). In this case the desired outcome is a single base class. If the base class uses a template it can't be used with other variants of the template since they are completely different classes: `Base<FooClass>` and `Base<BarClass>` have nothing in common - e.g. can't be placed in a single container.

Answer (score 0):

No, it's not safe.

I'm going to refractor the code so that it's necessary the user call a member function to perform this initialisation. It's not as automatic as I'd like, but it's probably for the best.

Comment: You probably can keep things automatic if you use CRTP. Consider this code: `template <class Derived> class Base { ... }; class Myclass : public Base<Myclass> { ... };` Now `Base` can call *static* functions of `Derived` all  day long, even in constructors.

Comment: Different types for a base class sort of miss the target. The various variants of `Base<>` are not related in any way - can't be used in lists, arrays, etc. together.